# How to make sure the position of the block is on the grid

Tags: c#, xna

Im a newbie trying to make Tetris. Now I have a block that is random(one of the 7 blocks) and now even though it does move on the grid,I use PositionX=15; so that it moves the distance of blocks(blocks are 15 by 15). The problem is I dont know how to make the blocks moving smoothly on grid(for example moving to left and right goes so fast and I dont know how to make it slower while still on the grid)
The Class Block looks like this:

```
public class Block
{


    public Vector2 Position;
    public bool[,] Vorm;
    protected int Rotation; // how many times it rotates
    protected int MaxRotation; // How many vorms of rotation
    protected int PositionX;
    protected int PositionY;
    protected Color color;
    protected Texture2D block;
    int BlockYspeed;
    int BlockXspeed;
    float FallTimer;  //  public bool FallingBlock = false;
    bool active;
    Random Random = new Random();
    int r;


    public Block()
    {
        this.Vorm = new bool[4, 4];
        r = Random.Next(0, 7);


    }


    public void LoadContent(ContentManager Content)
    {

        block = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Block");
    }
    public bool[,] blokvorm
    {
        get
        {
            int x = 4;
            int y = 4;
            bool[,] Vorm = new bool[x, y];
            for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
                {
                    Vorm[i, j] = false;

                }


            int r = Random.Next(7);
            switch (r)
            {
                case 0:
                    Vorm = StatusBlock.IBlock1;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Vorm = StatusBlock.TBlock1;

                    break;
                case 2:
                    Vorm = StatusBlock.ZBlock1;

                    break;
                case 3:
                    Vorm = StatusBlock.JBlock1;

                    break;
                case 4:
                    Vorm = StatusBlock.LBlock1;

                    break;
                case 5:
                    Vorm = StatusBlock.SBlock1;

                    break;
                case 6:
                    Vorm = StatusBlock.OBlock1;

                    break;





                default:

                    break;

            }


            return Vorm;
        }
    }


    public virtual void rotation()
    { }

    public void HandleInput()
    {
        if (Tetris.inputHelper.KeyPressed(Keys.Down))
        {
            PositionY += 15;

        }
        if (Tetris.InputHelper.KeyPressed(Keys.Up))
        {
            Rotation += 1;
            if (Rotation == MaxRotation)
                Rotation = 0;
            rotation();

        }
        if (Tetris.InputHelper.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
        {
            PositionX -= 15;
        } 
        if (Tetris.InputHelper.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
        {
            PositionX += 15;

        }

    }
    public void Collision()
    { 



    }



    public void speed(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        double SpeedCounter = 3;
        int LevelCounter = 1;
        if (LevelCounter < Tetris.GameWorld.level)
        {
            SpeedCounter -= 0.5;
            LevelCounter++;
        }
        FallTimer += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
        if (Math.Round(FallTimer, 1) == SpeedCounter)
        {
            FallTimer = 0;
            BlockYspeed = 15;
            BlockXspeed = 15;
            PositionY = PositionY += BlockYspeed;
            //BlockPosition.Y += 15;

        }
    }






    public void Update(GameTime gametime)
    {
        BlockYspeed = 15;
        HandleInput();
        Collision();
        PositionX += BlockXspeed;
        PositionY += BlockYspeed;


    }


    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, ContentManager Content)

    {
        //block = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Block");
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        // if (!FallingBlock)
        {
            Vector2 BlockPosition;
            BlockPosition = new Vector2(90 + PositionX, 0 + PositionY);
            DrawBlock(spriteBatch, BlockPosition);

            spriteBatch.End();
        }
    }

    private void DrawBlock(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, Vector2 Position)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                if (this.Vorm[i, j])
                    spriteBatch.Draw(block, Position + new Vector2(i * block.Width, j * block.Height), this.color);

    }
}
```

I have the 7 different blocks in different class and Ive a statusblock class where all the vorms of the blocks are in it.

Then I thought to make sure the blocks are on the grid I have to make this in the GameWorld class:

```
   public void AddToGrid(Block.Vorm b, int x, int y)
    {
        Vector2 gridPos = (Tetris.screen - new Vector2(grid.GetLength(0) * CellSize, grid.GetLength(1) * CellSize) / 2);
        b.Position = gridPos + new Vector2(x * CellSize, y * CellSize);
        grid[x, y] = b;

    }
```

problem is: It gives a error that vorm does not exist in Block how to solve this to make the block is on the grid?

Edit:
update code (another one but same function):

```
      public enum CanIPlaceBlock
    {
        Yes, No, OutOfScreen
    }
    public CanIPlaceBlock canIPlaceBlock(bool[,] grid, bool[,] Vorm, int x, int y)
    {
        for (int a = 0; a <Vorm.GetLength(0); a++)
            for(int b=0; b<Vorm.GetLength(1);b++)
            {
                int PositionX = x + a;
                int PositionY = y + b;

                if (Vorm[a, b] == false)
                {
                    if(PositionX<0 || PositionX>grid.GetLength(0))
                    {
                        return CanIPlaceBlock.OutOfScreen;
                    }
                    if(PositionY >grid.GetLength(1) || grid[a,b]==false)
                    {
                        return CanIPlaceBlock.No;
                    }
                }

            }
        return CanIPlaceBlock.Yes;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The specific error you're getting is because you are trying to use a class member as a type.  `Block.Vorm` references a member of the `Block` class, which is not valid in this case.

Try:

```
public void AddToGrid(Block b, int x, int y)
{
    Vector2 gridPos = (Tetris.screen - new Vector2(grid.GetLength(0) * CellSize, grid.GetLength(1) * CellSize) / 2);
    b.Position = gridPos + new Vector2(x * CellSize, y * CellSize);
    grid[x, y] = b;
}
```

That said, I suspect that you need to adjust your game logic somewhat.

The current falling tetromino is a collection of (for classic Tetris) 4 unit blocks in a particular arrangement.  Once the tetromino is placed in its final position those blocks become part of the layout.  So try treating the tetromino itself as a separate entity that interacts with the layout instead of something that exists within the layout.

Think of the tetromino as a separate entity that exists in a layer 'above' the layout but is bound by the contents of it.  Once the tetromino can no longer move down any further work out which 4 cells in the layout you will be placing the blocks into and destroy the tetromino object, or reset it with the next arrangement.  Then do your filled line detection, etc.

Comment: So what you are saying is once it cant move down any further the block layer becomes the same as the grid layer? Btw isnt the code the same as mine? it still gives an error on it. edit: nvm i see it but it still gives error

Comment: No, the code differs in the type passed as the first parameter.  I didn't change anything else.  And yes, when the tetromino is blocked from moving further down the component blocks are placed in the grid layer.

Comment: It still gives error though. but since I dont work with layers does it go automatically?

Comment: Update your question with the current error and I'll see if I can help.

Comment: Kinda updated because Im working with my friend he updated the code saying this would be better. the problem is I know what enum is but how would this work?